# Request functions are executing out of order in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to make a scraper, but I cant seem to get the code to execute in the right order. I need the album/albumart request function to execute after the title and artist function. I know node.js is weird about this sort of thing, but I've tried moving things all over and still no luck.

[Here's the Code](http://pastebin.com/Cb1RurJW)

Please pardon the mess and excess debug code.

Current output:

```
TESTED!!!
req
No error
Pentemple - Pazuzu 2
Now Playing: Pentemple - Pazuzu 2
10
Pentemple
10
Pentemple
1
{ artist: '',
  title: '',
  album: '',
  albumArt: '',
  testval: 'TESTED!!!' }
xtest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the asynchronous request calls, the responses might not be in order therefore to keep the order, you will need to make next request call in previous request's callback. Below is the example for the same -

```js
request(url1, function(err, res, html){
  if(!err)
  {
    // url1 successfully returned , call another dependent url
    request(url2, function(err2, res2, html2){
      if(!err2)
      {
        // url2 successfully returned,  go on with another request call and so on ... 
      }
    });
  }
  else
  {
    // first call failed, return gracefully here --
    callback(err); // if you have any
  }  
})
```

However, as suggested in earlier answer as well, this is anti pattern and will result in messy and cluttered code known as pyramid of doom or callback hell.

I would suggest going with wonderful **async** npm module and then the same code can be written as -

```js
var async = require('async');

async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        request(url1, function(error, res, html){
          
           callback(null, res, html);  
          
        });
        
    },
    function(res1, html1, callback) {
       
         request(url1, function(error, res, html){
          
           callback(null, res1, html1, res, html);  
          
        }); 
        
    } // ... AND SO ON
    
], function (err, result) {
  
  // the result contains the response sent by the last request callback
  if(!err)
  {
    // use your data 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases performing a request in Javascript has an asynchronous nature. That means that requests do not block the entire process. To perform and action when the request is done callbacks are used. Callbacks are functions that are added into the event loop queue once the request gets in finished state. The easiest way (but for sure not the best one) to make reqeust run one after another is to call second request in the first callback, third request in seconds callback and so on.

```
 request(profileurl, function (error, response, html) {
    console.log("req");
    if (!error) {
         // ...
         request(albumurl, function (error, response, html) { 
             if (!error) {
             // ...
             request(albumurl, function (error, response, html) {
             // ...
             });
         });
    } else {
        console.log("ERROR: " + error);
    }
});
```

But such a practice is considered to be anti-pattern and is called [Pyramid of Doom](http://calculist.org/blog/2011/12/14/why-coroutines-wont-work-on-the-web/), because nesting callbacks make the code unreadable, hard to to test and hard to maintain.

Good practice is considered to use [promises](https://spring.io/understanding/javascript-promises). They come "in box" with [ES2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/). But if you use ES5, you should use some additional module for them like: [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) or [Q](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is asynchronous. If the requests are dependent on each other I recommend using [callbacks](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/) so that when one request is complete, it calls the next one.